# Determining pixel coordinates across display resolutions

Tags: image-processing, resolution, screen-resolution

If a program displays a pixel at X,Y on a display with resolution A, can I *precisely* predict at what coordinates the same pixel will display at resolution B?

**MORE INFORMATION**

The 2 display resolutions are:

A-->1366 x 768

B-->1600 x 900

Dividing the max resolutions in each direction yields:

X-direction scaling factor = 1600/1366 = 1.171303075

Y-direction scaling factor = 900/768 = 1.171875

Say for example that the only red pixel on display A occurs at pixel (1,1).  If I merely scale up using these factors, then on display B, that red pixel will be displayed at pixel (1.171303075, 1.171875).  I'm not sure how to interpret that, as I'm used to thinking of pixels as integer values.  It might help if I knew the exact geometry of pixel coordinates/placement on a screen.  e.g., do pixel coordinates (1,1) mean that the center of the pixel is at (1,1)?  Or a particular corner of the pixel is at (1,1)?  I'm sure diagrams would assist in visualizing this--if anyone can post a link to helpful resources, I'd appreciate it.  And finally, I may be approaching this all wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem is related to the field of [scaling/resampling images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(bitmap)). Bitmap-, or raster images are *digital photographs*, so they are the most common form to represent natural images that are rich in detail. The term bitmap refers to how a given pattern (bits in a pixel) maps to a specific color. A bitmap images take the form of an array, where the value of each element, called a pixel picture element, correspond to the color of that region of the image.

### Sampling

When measuring the value for a pixel, one takes the average color of an area around the location of the pixel. A simplistic model is sampling a square, and a more accurate measurement is to calculate a weighted Gaussian average. When perceiving a bitmap image the human eye should blend the pixel values together, recreating an illusion of the continuous image it represents.

### Raster dimensions

The number of horizontal and vertical samples in the pixel grid is called raster dimensions, it is specified as `width x height`.

### Resolution

Resolution is a measurement of sampling density, resolution of bitmap images give a relationship between pixel dimensions and physical dimensions. The most often used measurement is `ppi`, *pixels per inch*.

### Scaling / Resampling

Image scaling is the name of the process when we need to create an image with different dimensions from what we have. A different name for scaling is resampling. When resampling algorithms try to reconstruct the original continuous image and create a new sample grid. There are two kind of scaling: **up** and **down**.

#### Scaling image down

The process of reducing the raster dimensions is called decimation, this can be done by averaging the values of source pixels contributing to each output pixel.

#### Scaling image up

When we increase the image size we actually want to create sample points between the original sample points in the original raster, this is done by interpolation the values in the sample grid, effectively guessing the values of the unknown pixels. This interpolation can be done by nearest-neighbor interpolation, bilinear interpolation, bicubic interpolation, etc. But the scaled up/down image must be also represented over discrete grid.

Comment: Thanks.  Most of that was useful, and it looks like the "raster dimension" and "Scaling image up" sections were most relevant.   But it sounds like the interpolation portion of 'Scaling image up' deals with digitally increasing the size of an electronic image.  To be clear, my issue deals with a 3rd party (Windows) application that can run at different resolutions.  The application isn't displaying images per se--it is displaying words, shapes, and patterns.  In this case, would I still need to investigate the type of interpolation done?  Or can I somehow calculate the new pixel location?

Comment: Do you also like to scale the words, shapes, etc. or their positions should be recalculated only?

Comment: I'm not the one doing the scaling.  The application is displaying on my screen at 2 "raster dimensions", 1366 x 768 and 1600 x 900.  I'd like to know how pixel locations shift between the two.  For example, if there is a red pixel at (X,Y) in display A, where is then in display B?

Comment: @cag8f there's no way to know without having details on the internal operations of the specific application, or doing *a lot* of experimentation and sleuthing. Even two different implementations of the same algorithm can give you different results.

Comment: OK got it--the answer is application dependent.  That is something I considered yesterday.  I know with websites, developers will decide exactly different elements are displayed at different screen widths.  Thanks for the info.